# Manipulate PHP stdClass output to have desired json format

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I am getting dataset from a database query as object. What I want to do is to manipulate current output and create an additional array to store some of the output to have it compatible for my json input in another call.

Current `json_encode($myObj)` output

```
[
  {
    "entry": "10",
    "displayid": "100",
    "folder": "1"
  },
  {
    "entry": "20",
    "displayid": "200",
    "folder": "2"
  },
  {
    "entry": "30",
    "displayid": "300",
    "folder": "3"
  }
]
```

What I am trying to have through this data is;

```
[
  {
    "file": {
      "entry": 10,
      "displayid": 100
    },
    "folder": 1
  },
  {
    "file": {
      "entry": 20,
      "displayid": 200
    },
    "folder": 2
  },
  {
    "file": {
      "entry": 30,
      "displayid": 300
    },
    "folder": 3
  }
]
```

I tried the following, but it gives me completely weird output;

```
foreach ($result as $res) {
    $ho = new stdClass();
    $ho->file = [$ho->entry = $res->entry, $ho->displayid = $res->displayid];
    $ho->folder = $res->folder;
}
```

Comment: Because you assign nonsense to your `$ho`. It should be `$ho->file->entry = $res->entry; $ho->file->displayid = $res->displayid`. But why are you playing with classes and not with associative array? `json_decode($myJson, true)` to get associative array instead of object

Comment: @Justinas Thanks for quick response, first I tried that way but I keep getting `Message: Creating default object from empty value` warning this way

Comment: @Justinas, Good point; I just didn't want to change the actual output structure; If I convert it to associative array, would there be any gain in terms of performance?

Comment: Final output will stay the same. And performance difference is way too little to be considered here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($result as $res) {
    $ho = new stdClass();
    $ho->file = (object)['entry' => $res->entry, 'displayid' => $res->displayid];
    $ho->folder = $res->folder;
    $newObj[] = $ho;
}
print_r($newObj);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately I am getting `Type: ParseError - Message: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ']'` on PHP 7.4.30

Comment: Sorry, my TYPO, fixed now see `=>` instead of  `=`